# awk does not write to file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using this command to print out some information from a transaction viewer. 
the command works fine if im running it in the terminal, but as soon i want the output to be written to a file, the file is empty.

```
omn_bdxtrc -s=10 -c=10 | awk '/BO2/{printf "%-5s %3d\n", $2,$7}' 2>/dev/null >> "/logs/transactions/temp2.txt"
```

If i only run `omn_bdxtrc -s=10 -c=10`  get the result in a table.

```
0618-16:48:07  Bdx         1sec avg/  max avg (  peak time)  total    Bytes:   Min      Max    Total
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0618-16:48:07 88-7-BO2         10.00/    10.00 (18/06 16:48)  31                117      117     3627
0618-16:48:07 91-1-NB18         0.00/     1.00 (18/06 16:48)  1                  77       77       77
0618-16:48:07 Total           85.00/    85.00 (18/06 16:48)  268
```

And if i use the AWK command.

```
omn_bdxtrc -s=10 -c=10 | awk '/BO2/{printf "%-5s %3d\n", $2,$7}'

88-7-BO2   9
88-7-BO2  20
88-7-BO2  30
88-7-BO2  39
88-7-BO2  50
88-7-BO2  59
```

Any ideas why the output to file is empty?

Comment: Does `omn_bdxtrc` exit or does it produce output continuously?

Comment: @TomFenech, Hi, well the thing is that when i run the command without write to file, it gives me an output.
(The search was a typo, i just want to search for BO2)

Another thing is that If i DON'T use awk, it writes to file

Comment: In that case, it sounds like it could be related to buffering (which is probably what @melpomene was referring to) . Some programs change their behaviour depending on whether they (think they) are writing to a pipe or a file. If you pipe to `omn_bdxtrc -s=10 -c=10 | cat > your_file`, what happens?

Comment: @TomFenech that command writes to file, no problem there. but as soon as i want the AWK to be included, the file is empty. :|

I also tried to pass an string to the file like this.  
omn_bdxtrc -s=2 -c=2 2| awk '/91-1/{printf "Hello World" }' | cat > /logs/transactions/temp2.txt but the file is still empty.
And as usual if I don't include the the write to file, the terminal keeps printing out Hello World.

Comment: @melpomene Hi. Yes. the produce is running continuously, and it seems that was the problem.

Comment: @Dymond That's probably awk buffering output until it has accumulated enough data for a burst write. You'll just have to wait a while. :-)

Comment: @melpomene you where completely right, this was the problem. I wanted real time write but the buffering didn't allow that :)
If you leave this as an answer  I can accept it